# is there non-blocking io in flash?

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3

is there non-blocking io in flash? I need it for my live chat project.
If not, please tell me what thing need if i make a live chat with the web cam in java.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no such think as blocking IO in flash, except maybe for loading file in air, but even that don't feel right (IMHO) considering the very non-bloking nature of most things in flash.

Look at red5.

Seriously though, this is a really bad question.